# Convert Python to Scala

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I am new with Scala and I used to work with python.

I want to convert program from Python to Scala and have difficulties with following 2 lines (create sql dataframe)

## python code

```
fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in schemaString.split()]
schema = StructType(fields)

data = dataset.map(lambda (filepath, text): (filepath.split("/")[-1],text, filepath.split("/")[-2]))
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, schema)
```

i have made this

## scala code

```
val category = dataset.map { case (filepath, text) => filepath.split("/")(6) }

val id = dataset.map { case (filepath, text) => filepath.split("/")(7) }

val text = dataset.map { case (filepath, text) => text }

val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField(id.toString(), StringType, true), 
  StructField(category.toString(), StringType, true), 
  StructField(text.toString(), StringType, true)
))
```

and now i am blocked there!

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I've though prograpython reference is a valuable context here. Have you removed it intentionally?

Comment: What's the problem? Error? I think that snippets don't tell anything right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it is worth I have converted your code literally and the following compiles using spark 2.3.2 on my machine

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import spark.implicits._

// Introduced to make code clearer
case class FileRecord(name: String, text: String)

// Whatever data set you have (a single record dataset is hard coded, replace with your data)
val dataSet =  Seq(FileRecord("/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i", "example contents")).toDS()

// Whatever you need with path length 6 and 7 hardcoded (you might want to change this)
// you may be able to do the following three map operations more efficiently
val category = dataSet.map { case FileRecord(filepath, text) => filepath.split("/")(6) }

val id = dataSet.map { case FileRecord(filepath, text) => filepath.split("/")(7) }

val text = dataSet.map { case FileRecord(filepath, text) => text }

val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField(id.toString(), StringType, true),
  StructField(category.toString(), StringType, true),
  StructField(text.toString(), StringType, true)
))
```